# Sending and Receiving Data Through Sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets

Okay, so Like the title says, I'm stumped on how to send, specifically, strings through input and output streams. I'm making a basic log in server and want to be able to hit "log in" and have the log in credentials to save on the server side. Here's what I have.

This is the try block inside the action event for my log in button:

```
                                try {
                                Socket socket = Client.s;
                                OutputStream dOut = Client.s.getOutputStream();
                                PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(dOut);

                                username = jTextField1.getText();
                                password = jPasswordField1.getText();

                                //System.out.println("Username: " + username);
                                //System.out.println("Password: " + password);

                                socketOut.println(username);
                                socketOut.flush();

                                socketOut.println(password);
                                socketOut.flush();

                                socketOut.println("Click");
                                socketOut.flush();


                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

And here's my code that's server sided. I attempted to receive and store the data but it isn't working and I'm not too sure why. I also have a couple of useless loops that I will eventually remove(ignore those):

```
 BufferedReader socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     String str = socketIn.readLine();
while (buttonClicked == false){
    int done = 0;
  String messageType = socketIn.toString();     
    while(done == 0) {

      switch(messageType)
      {
      case "username": // Type A
          username = socketIn.toString();
        System.out.println("username: " + username);
        break;
      case "password": // Type B
          password = socketIn.toString();
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
        break;
      case "Click":
          buttonClicked = true;
          break;
      }
```

Please note that I know that I'm missing closing brackets, I only copied part of my code.

Comment: The client sends 3 lines. First line is the user name, second line is the password, third line is "Click" (not sure what the point of this third line is). So, the server should read 3 lines: the first read line will be the user name, the second read line will be the password, and the third read line will be "Click". See the symmetry? Reading a line consists in calling readLine(), which returns the line read. Your switch doesn't make sense. Calling toString() on the reader doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     String str = socketIn.readLine();
while (buttonClicked == false){
    int done = 0;
  String messageType = socketIn.toString();     
    while(done == 0) {

      switch(messageType)
      {
      case "username": // Type A
          username = socketIn.toString();
        System.out.println("username: " + username);
        break;
      case "password": // Type B
          password = socketIn.toString();
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
        break;
      case "Click":
          buttonClicked = true;
          break;
      }
```

You take the `.toString()` of the stream (`socketIn.toString();`), you should use `str`.

```
BufferedReader socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     String str = socketIn.readLine();
while (buttonClicked == false){
    int done = 0;  
    while(done == 0) {

      switch(str)
      {
      case "username": // Type A
          username = str;
        System.out.println("username: " + username);
        break;
      case "password": // Type B
          password = str;
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
        break;
      case "Click":
          buttonClicked = true;
          break;
      }
```

But, anyway i think it's not what you want... i mean when him pass "password", password will be password.

Maybe you want

```
BufferedReader socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     String str = socketIn.readLine();
while (buttonClicked == false){
    int done = 0;  
    while(done == 0) {

      switch(str)
      {
      case "username": // Type A
          username = socketIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("username: " + username);
        break;
      case "password": // Type B
          password = socketIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
        break;
      case "Click":
          buttonClicked = true;
          break;
      }
```

To read a new line from input.